# Why does :!python3 differ from g:python3_host_prog?

Tags: neovim, python

I am using Ubuntu 22 and the default (OS) Python version is 3.10.6.

I don't need this python version; rather I need 3.8.16. I've installed it and
set the `g:python3_host_prog` to its path to use it when I use NeoVim.

But I've noticed that when I run `:!python3 -V` it outputs the default Python
version which is 3.10.6. I guess it still looks for the `python` executable in
`PATH` and finds the first instance of it. I don't really understand the purpose
of `python3_host_prog` if it doesn't temporarily change the provider for the
running instance of NeoVim.

Is there a way to force NeoVim to use the wanted version? Why are they
different?

Currently my temporary solution is to wrap the NeoVim command by adding a prefix
of the wanted executable while it runs and then remove it using bash.

Comment: Did you found an answer to your question? Is the answer proposed addressed your problem? If so I'll be glad if you could accept it. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 3 access to Python from Vim/Neovim that can be configured differently:

1. The shell access (when running `:!python3 -v`)
2. The python linked to Vim/Neovim (when running `:py3 print(sys.version)`
3. The python used by [coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim)
4. The python used by [deoplete](https://github.com/Shougo/deoplete.nvim)

## The shell access

The python version is here the one used by the shell and it is selected the same way it is selected for the shell using the `PATH` environment variable.

Remark: I believe the first `python3` executable  in your `path` is still `Python 3.10.6` which makes it the default shell Python and the default Vim shell Python.

To change that you should to adapt the your `PATH` environment variable to make Python 3.8.16 the first Python found by the shell.

## The python linked to Vim/Neovim

It is the Python version used by a number of plugin using Python (e.g.: [ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips))

In particular if you are using deoplete

### For Vim

This one is defined when Vim is linked (it depend on the compilation/linkage of Vim/Neovim). You can't change it without recompiling Vim/Neovim or changing the Vim/Neovim executable you are using.

### For Neovim

It is determined by the value of `g:python3_host_prog`

## Python used by `coc`

The `coc` plugins used Python interpreter to determine how to complete Python code. You can configure the interpreter used by changing the `python.pythonPath` parameter of the `~/.vim/coc-settings.json` that you can edit with the `:CocConfig` command.

coc-settings.json

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python3"
}
```

## Python used by `deoplete-jedi`

It is determined by the value of `g:python3_host_prog`

It is important it correspond to the version of Python you are using if you want deoplete to complete correctly the method of the python package you are using.